# My Android studio Drawable Resource Folder Imports in a very crowded manner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, image-scaling

I'm currently following a tutorial, Currently, it is required to import multiple images drawable folders for different densities by simply copying and pasting it to android studio
[picture of the Folder from which we import the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf1co.png)

[Image of the tutorial after pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX3vH.png)

[and This is Me after pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/174Vm.png)

as you can see me pasting, Creates a directory for each image with the corresponding density
which makes the drawable folder very crowded, so am I doing something wrong ? or this is new in android studio ? because I remember an old project of mine which didn't import it like that, Thank you for your time and be patient with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no problem. It is the view that you are using which is different. If you want yours to look like the on in the tutorial, you should go right to the top of that window (that shows you) and look for the android "face" or sign with the word "Android" next to it and an arrow pointing downwards and click on that android sign. A dropdown menu will open up and then you should choose the "Project" option option. Now your files will look like the ones in the tutorials.

Check this website if you are confused :

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects

Comment: yea that was it , Thank you so much ! <3

Answer (score 0):

You might be using **Project** View , try changing it to **Android** View.

You can find it on the top-left corner.

Comment: yea , it was actually the other way around , thank you <3

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks.